# Merge hex and opacity

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic3

I have `CSS` class like below. Can I get the one `hex` value instead of both? In other words, merge both and return `hex` value.

```
.my-class{
   background-color: #50A2A7;
   opacity: 0.41;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use **HEX** value for opacity, you have to switch to **RGBA** like this :

```
background-color: rgba(80, 162, 167, 0.41);
```

Comment: Oh.. Excellent. I have huge issues with `opacity`. This is the perfect solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: welcome, you can learn more about it here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp

Comment: Thanks. Did you use any tool to convert `hex` to `RGB`?

Comment: That's not true, [new specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation) now allow hex format to include opacity channel: #RRGGBBAA or #RGBA even though only Firefox currently supports this.

Comment: i use the chrome Console for conversion but you can try this link : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, Safari and chrome support this 8digits notation too.

Comment: An easy trick is also using chrome's element inspect to change HEX to RGBA and otherwise. See this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/gndcsl

Answer (score 1):

The HEX value for this combination will be #B9D9DB. But, by using this value instead, there will of course not be any transparency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [newer css specs for hex codes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_color_hexa):

```
.my-class2{
   background-color: #50A2A769;
}
```

The last 2 digits are for opacity, with values between 00 and FF

Answer (score 0):

You would currently need to convert the hex value into a RGB value, then use `rgba()`. To convert there are a number of web-based services you can convert between hex and rgb, like [this one](https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/hex-to-rgb/).

Once you have the rgb value, you can use `rgba()` with your opacity value.

```
.my-class{
  background-color: rgba(80, 162, 167, 0.41);
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.class1 {
  background-color: #50A2A7;
  opacity: 0.41;
}

.class2 {
  background-color: rgba(80, 162, 167, 0.41);
}
```

```html
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@sampath 
there cannot be a class having css as background-color in hex and having the opacity value in the same style line
you can go for the rgba style background-color:rgba(80, 161, 165, 0.41) and hsla style background-color:hsla(183, 35%, 48%, 0.41)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site. [Hexcolortool](https://www.hexcolortool.com/) You can find the perfect opacity of the color you need. You have to use RGBA which leads to the fouth value which is the opacity

**Ex:** `rgba(80, 162, 167, 0.41)`

**Opacity:** `41%`

> 41%

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(80, 162, 167, 0.41);
}
```

> 100%

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(80, 162, 167, 1);
}
```